# Error message "This version of Windows is not authentic"

Tags: windows-7, boot, 64-bit, windows-registry

I have been using Windows 7 on my computer for about 2 years and for about a year, I have this message appearing. It started after I did some hardware upgrade. My search on the web indicates that an authentic CD is necessary to fix the problem. I have a OEM version of Windows and the only way to remove the error is to reinstall Windows in a new configuration (OEM versions will not repair an installation). Since this means I need to reinstall all my applications, it takes about a week to get everything set up. Can someone tell me where to find the authentication key in the register so I can save it when I reinstall Windows (for the 4th time).

Answer (score 4):

You can re activate new PC by telephone, you may get prompt to say how many PC's this copy of Windows is installed on.

Comment: I believe that they will ask for money (something I want to avoid) since OEM versions don't have support.

Comment: @LDC3 Activation support from Microsoft is always free.

Comment: It's free and this is upgrading of hardware is a very common use case. Don't hesitate to call.

Answer (score 0):

Boot from Install CD and run the Start Up Diagnostics/Repair.

To do this;

Boot from CD,

At setup welcome, click the "Repair Computer" button on the bottom left.

Now select Startup repair from the list.

As to if there is a larger problem with your computer. Have a look through the event viewer for errors and post back here is a good start.

Comment: This won't work. You didn't read the question where I stated that the OEM version will not do a Computer Repair.

Comment: Then the only legal option is to contact your OEM. There are many ways for authentication but they are illegal.

Comment: Please check the time and date that is shown in the bottom right hand corner of your Windows 7 screen display or XP if that is what you are using. For security reasons, you will not be able to authenticate with an incorrect date in the bios setting. You can reset it on your screen or in the bios.

Comment: I'm not asking for a key, I'm just asking where to find the key in the register, which should not be illegal since it is on my computer.